# Different font size - Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, font-size

I'm working on a project and I noticed something strange. The font looks different in chrome than firefox. You can see better in the image below : [image: different font size : chrome vs ff]

As you can see, between "help" and the margin, in chrome are 33px and in firefox 57px. Does somebody has any idea about this?

PS : font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif; and I use a css reset.

Comment: I don't see a different in font size. Only the padding.

Comment: Your font size is the same!  I strongly suggest that you edit your OP title to more accurately describe the **actual** problem of inconsistent padding/margins/positions.

Answer (score 0):

start your css document off with

```
* { 
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing his code, I'd be hesitant to recommend anything let alone a blanket reset on padding & margin.  It may be totally ineffective or completely over-ridden.

Comment: I use https://github.com/iamntz/base-project (has css reset) so what you wrote is already done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your using Firefox version 4 or below. If you are then I believe your problem is in the rendering engine for Firefox versions 4 and below, it has only just been corrected in Firefox 5.

Basically Firefox 4 and below have a differant measurement for a CSS unit to all other browsers, I have had to abandon fonts because of this inconsistent behavior in the past.

Have a look under "Consistent CSS Units" at the [Mozilla Firefox tech specs page for version 5](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/technology/#css)

I hope this helps you

Comment: A pixel is still a pixel.  What are you talking about?    His fonts look the same... everything is simply shifted left including some of his non-text elements.

Comment: @Sparky672 Physically a pixel is a pixel but a pixel size can vary depending on the engine generating the content as any good designer should be aware of. The font aspect I mentioned was an example and not the be all and end all. Have a look at the Mozilla reference, it's small but clear.

Comment: I tried to use em,px,pt but without any good result. Maybe this will help to see better my problem http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/unled203.png/

Comment: @Ryan:  As any good designer knows, "pixels" have no physical size whatsoever until we start talking about how many of them are rendered across a monitor at a given screen resolution.  On a given monitor, one pixel in Firefox is the same exact "size" as one pixel in any other browser... period.

Comment: @Sparky672 you are mis-informed my friend. If a pixel has a physical dimension or it cannot exist, that is like saying air has no physical or measurable value and this is just not correct. The ratios for the pixel dimension is initially set by the hardware displaying the pixel and the size of the pixel itself is defined by the generation of the pixel. Just read the information provided by Mozilla as previously stated.

Comment: @Ryan:  It's intellectually dishonest to ignore half of what I wrote to claim that I'm mis-informed.  Pixels do **not** have a physical size **UNTIL we start talking about how many of them are rendered across a monitor at a given screen resolution.**  They only "physically" exist as dependent upon the graphics hardware, therefore for the same hardware, individual pixels **cannot** be one size in one browser and a totally different size in another browser.

Comment: I ignored nothing, do your homework and read the reference, the information you're providing is incorrect, "We’ve changed our handling of pixel sizes to match Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome so that 1 inch always equals 96 pixels" ref: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/technology/#css

Comment: @Ryan:  My statements are not in contradiction with that.  Perhaps you can demonstrate your knowledge by explaining the referenced concept in detail as well as exactly how it applies to the OP's issue as well as your answer.

Comment: Yeah, your comments are actually in contradiction to that. You clearly lack understanding so do your homework instead of using me as your personal tutor.